# No Executable output when running 'dotnet run' after installing .NET core

Tags: .net-core

I installed .NET Core following the instructions at the link below

http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/

and I was able to get my 'hello world' working using 'dotnet run'. However, I couldn't see an exe file that all the documentation around the internet seems to indicate it would generate.

Running 'dotnet publish' pretty much copies those files into a different folder with 2 less files (removes the pdb file and the extra dev configs).

What am I missing?

**Update 1**

Here is the project.json file I have

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-23930"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Users should now upgrade to RC2 bits from nightly, http://dot.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will only get a binary executable (exe file on Windows) when publishing a "self-contained" application (See [Types of portability in .NET Core](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/app-types.html)).  Note: I'm using the current preview1 build version (`1.0.0-rc2-3002702`) for all `Microsoft.NetCore.App` references, but the same changes apply to other versions.

Basically, your project.json file should have the following changes:

1.
Add a new section called `runtimes`:

```
"runtimes": {
  "win7-x64": {}
}
```

2.
Remove the `platform` part of the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` dependency:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "type": "platform",
  "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
}
```

Changes to:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
```

3.
Ensure that you are targetting `netcoreapp1.0` and not `netstandard1.*`, `netstandard1.*` indicates that you are compiling a class library and not a standalone executable program.  Your frameworks section should then look like:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {}
}
```

Once these changes are made, you can then publish your app as a binary executable ("self-contained") application with this command:

`dotnet publish -r win7-x64`

Comment: Somehow completely missed this answer! Thanks!

Comment: Solved my problem.For Ubuntu runtime is named "ubuntu.16.04-x64"

Comment: `ubuntu.14.04-x64` for Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and `ubuntu.16.04-x64` for Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

Answer (score -1):

The exe should be under the `bin\Debug` folder. However, you'll only get an exe if you add `emitEntryPoint:true` in project.json like [here](https://github.com/aspnet/dotnet-watch/blob/dev/src/dotnet-watch/project.json#L5)

Comment: That is exactly what all the documentation says but no exe. The 'dotnet new' request does that automatically (adds emitEntryPoint:true) all by itself but still, no exe. I will update the question with my project.json